# Escape multiple double quotes

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I have a sheet with the following value:

`{"billing":{"NIP (tylko firma)":"123-12-12-123","Firma":"Google"},"shipping":{"NIP (tylko firma)":"123-12-12-123","Nazwa firmy":"Google"}}`

I want to extract the first `123-12-12-123` from a given cell and output it into another cell in a different sheet.

I have attempted to use `FIND` but I am having trouble because of all the quotes.

Comment: I assume you mean the first number string matching that *nnn-nn-nn-nnn* format, rather than literally that text?

Comment: Perhaps a simpler method would be to paste your source data in using the wizard, and separating using " as the delimiter?

Comment: @Rory The problem with this is that not all the  cells will follow that formatting. some will just be 10 numbers, some will have a - in different locations.

Comment: So what's the common factor? The first item with numbers in it? The third item between colons? Something else?

Comment: @Rory It would be everything after at least `billing":{"NIP (tylko firma)":"` and before the next `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(""":""",A1)+3,LEN(A1)),FIND("""",MID(A1,FIND(""":""",A1)+3,LEN(A1)))-1)
```

Comment: That's it! Below is my modified code

`=LEFT(MID(orders!AY1;FIND(""":""";orders!AY1)+3;LEN(orders!AY1));FIND("""";MID(orders!AY1;FIND(""":""";orders!AY1)+3;LEN(orders!AY1)))-1)`

Thank you